# Div layout puzzle for window resizing

Tags: html

I am trying to make my webpage (www.webspacegallery.com) change layouts nicely with different window sizes/resolutions.

I think I have done a pretty decent job so far. However I'm a bit stuck with the current problem.

Screenshots here of what I am trying to do:

http://www.webspacegallery.com/big.jpg

To:

http://www.webspacegallery.com/small.jpg

Does anyone know what the best div layout would be for this?

Current code:

```
<div class="video-container">
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/57042874?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1" height="540" width="960" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content1"></div>
<div class="content2"></div>
</div>

.content1{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 34%;
    min-width: 200px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace
    border: 0px #aaa solid;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.content2 {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 64%;
    min-width: 200px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 0px #aaa solid;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Ok...? No need to remove the whole post lol. What if somebody else could have benefited from it?

Comment: Have you looked at BootStrap? http://getbootstrap.com/ this comes full of useful pre-built classes including responsive design and a grid system http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 1):

#### I personally use Foundation.

Foundation is a free, easy to learn templating system for creating fluid grids and layouts.

View Here: http://foundation.zurb.com/index.html

**For example, try resizing your browser here:**

#### http://www.sinsysonline.com/secondhomehostel

The classes are ridiculously easy to learn, and the documentation is precise and concise.

---

Here is a free setup to play and tinker with the foundation to learn if you'd like to utilize it or not. It really is a very nice library.

#### http://codepen.io/mhayes/pen/qdCAc

**Let me know if you want an expanded solution in a Fiddle for instance.**